# Colored output does not work anymore with latest Win10 Fall Creators Update

Tags: python, powershell, windows-10

I was working in python with escape code `\033` to create a colored output with python's `print()` function on Win10 e.g. a blue colored text with

```
print('\033[94mBlue_Text\033[0m')
```

I updated to the lates fall creators update on Win10 and now my colored output doesn't work anymore. I'm getting following output:

[image: python output]

I'm missing something?

Comment: You might want to try asking this in Superuser.

Comment: The console's virtual terminal support is initially disabled. Your script needs to call `GetConsoleMode` on a handle for the active screen buffer (typically standard output, but you can also open "CONOUT$"), enable the `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING` flag, and update the mode by calling `SetConsoleMode`.

Comment: As to why it worked before, CMD enables the console's VT support in Windows 10. Earlier implementations mistakenly left it enabled for child processes. If you had run python.exe directly from Explorer (e.g. double clicking on a .py script) instead of from CMD, then Python would have allocated its own console with VT mode disabled.

Comment: Thanks! I was googling a little bit more and found out that you can set a default value in the registry for the default behaviour. Maybe this was changed in the last update - Set (or create) REG_DWORD "VirtualTerminalLevel" to 0x1 in ‘HKCU\Console’. Now it works again (I rather set the default value in windows than changing my python code)

Comment: It would be helpful if Microsoft documented that setting rather than casually mention it in a [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/06/20/understanding-windows-console-host-settings) without even specifying the valid values.

Comment: Anyway, you'll be forcing everyone who uses your code to either modify the console default setting or use `start` to run Python with a custom window title and modify the respective subkey setting -- all to save about 5 lines of code. Enabling it manually would also tell you whether VT mode is supported, so you could fall back on using colorama, for example.

Comment: Set (or create) REG_DWORD "VirtualTerminalLevel" to 0x1 in ‘HKCU\Console’. Put the Value to "1"